# Filter rows based on two criteria in dplyr

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

Sample data:

```
y <- c(sort(sample(0:100, 365,replace = T)),sort(sample(0:100, 365,replace = T)))
df <- data.frame(loc.id = rep(1:2,each = 365), day = rep(1:365,times = 2), y = y,ref.day = 250)
```

I want to select all the first row where y > 20, y > 40, y > 60 and y > 80 for each `loc.id`

```
df %>% group_by(loc.id) %>% dplyr::filter(any(y > 20)) %>% # additional check
    dplyr::slice(unique(c(which.max(y > 20), which.max(y > 40),which.max(y > 60),which.max(y > 80)))) %>% ungroup() 

    # A tibble: 8 x 4
      loc.id   day     y ref.day
      <int> <int> <int>   <dbl>
    1      1    78    21     250
    2      1   154    41     250
    3      1   225    61     250
    4      1   288    81     250
    5      2    79    21     250
    6      2   147    41     250
    7      2   224    61     250
    8      2   300    81     250
```

I want to include an additional statement which is that if after slicing `day` is  > `ref.day`, then select the row where day is equal to ref.day instead. 
In this case, it would look like:

```
  # A tibble: 8 x 4
        loc.id   day    y ref.day
        <int> <int> <int>   <dbl>
    1      1    78    21     250
    2      1   154    41     250
    3      1   225    61     250
    4      1   288    81     250 # this row will not be selected. Instead row where day == 250 will be here instead 
    5      2    79    21     250
    6      2   147    41     250
    7      2   224    61     250
    8      2   300    81     250 # this row will not be selected. Instead row where day == 250 will be here instead
```

Comment: Please use `set.seed` for reproducibility

Comment: I am not following the  logic for filtering the last row for each 'loc.id' because in the `slice`, you are already using the expression `which.max(y > 80)`  Suppose, if there is no row that matches the day == 250.  The reason is `df %>% group_by(loc.id) %>% filter(any(y > 20)) %>% slice(y == ref.day)
# A tibble: 0 x 4`.  In the sample I used, the max of 'y' is 100